# Android: Code crashes when trying to pick contact

Tags: android

I'm using this code for picking contacts:

```
        contactsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 1001);  
            }
         });
```

In debug node I get "sorce not found" on startActivityForResult

***Edit :***  works, just had to change BOTH code and emulator to API 5+

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;

Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 1001);
```

Comment: Eclipse sais "The import android.provider.ContactsContract cannot be resolved"